# PHP - What is the best way to access a property of an object which is an array element

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have an object which is an array of JSON objects. Kinda Like this,

```
$object = [
 {
   "id":1,
   "name":"blue",
   "order":4
  },
 {
   "id":2,
   "name":"green",
   "order":6
  },
 {
   "id":3,
   "name":"yellow",
   "order":2
  }
]
```

I wanted to access the properties in a simple way and a single line maybe like this,

> Say if I wanted the "order" of the object with name "blue"
>
> > $blue_order = $object[something]->[name="blue"]->order;

Kinda mixed Jquery in this. But I hope you understand. Right now the best I've got is this,

```
for($i=0; $i<count($object); $i++){
 if($object[$i]->name == "blue"){
  $blue_order = $object[$i]->order;
 }
}
```

This seems very inefficient though and I don't want to use a loop because the array is very large and looping through it will be very slow. So how do I do this?

> I used a "for" loop instead of foreach because the array can be null. And also the order of the array elements will not always be the same.

So I can't do something like

```
$object[0]->order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
 array('id'=>1,'name'=>'blue','order'=>4),
 array('id'=>2,'name'=>'green','order'=>6),
 array('id'=>3,'name'=>'yellow','order'=>2),    
);

// $json is JSON version of the arrays in $arr
$json = json_encode($arr);

// show $json
echo $json . "\n";

// create arrays from JSON so it can be used in PHP easier
$obj = json_decode($json);

$color = 'blue';
$blue_order = array_filter($obj, function($i) use ($color) { return $i->name == $color; })[0]->order;

echo "Blue Order: " . $blue_order;
```

You may be able to use array_filter to help this become a one-liner. I included the json_decode and json_encode so I could have a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use `foreach` but check if the array isn't empty first, like this:

```
if(!empty($object)){
  foreach($object as $element){
    if($element->name == "blue"){
      $blue_order = $element->order;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your code looks efficient to me, what I would probably add is a `break` after you find the value, like this:

```
if(!empty($object)){
  foreach($object as $element){
    if($element->name == "blue"){
      $blue_order = $element->order;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If your object has a lot of information and you're going to do a lot of searches, then you could do some pre-processing so it get easier to search, like this:

```
$object_by_name = array();
if(!empty($object)){
  foreach($object as $element){
    $object_by_name[$element->name] = $element;
  }
}
```

Then, you could search it like this:

```
if(!empty($object_by_name['blue'])){
  $blue_order = $object_by_name['blue']->order
}
```

Comment: hmmmm... I liked your pre-processing idea. I think I'm gonna try that. Thanks

Comment: Cool, let us know how it goes

Comment: although, the array I'm using is very large (and I mean very very large ) and creating another array like that will be a little inefficient. But I guess it's the best I've got right now.

Comment: I think putting a break will be better than creating another array. What do you say? I'm confused.

Comment: Well, if you don't need the information from the first array after doing the pre-processing, then you could create the name keys in the same array while ditching the current numeric key. If you're searching a lot, I'd say you should go for the pre-processing, but that would really depend on the data

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

You're writing way too much code.

```
$array_list = ($array_list)?:[];
$array_list = array_filter($array_list,function($var) {
    return ($var->name=="blue");
});
$order = ($array_list)? $array_list[0]->order :'';
```